# dot indicator below the carousel slider moving along with other items - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, carousel, dot

I am using carousel slider package with smooth page indicator package to display the list of post items in Listview.builder.

I have successfully showing both the post and indicator in UI.

But my problem is while i swipe the images in first item, the dot indicator for all the items are moving along with it.

This is the code.

```
 final CarouselController _controller = CarouselController();

CarouselSlider(
                              carouselController: _controller,
                              options: CarouselOptions(
                                height: 160.h,
                                enlargeCenterPage: false,
                                autoPlay: false,
                                aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                                onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _current = index;
                                  });
                                },
                                autoPlayCurve: Curves.easeInBack,
                                enableInfiniteScroll:
                                    dList[index].postUrl!.length == 1
                                        ? false
                                        : true,
                                autoPlayAnimationDuration:
                                    Duration(seconds: 10),
                                viewportFraction: 1.2,
                              ),
                              items: name.map((item) {
                                return Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                  child: Container(
                                    height: 200.h,
                                    width: 350.w,
                                    margin:
                                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0),
                                    child: InkWell(
                                      onTap: () {
                                        Navigator.push(context,
                                            MaterialPageRoute(builder:
                                                (BuildContext context) {
                                          return Scaffold(
                                            // backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                                            extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
                                            appBar: AppBar(
                                              backgroundColor:
                                                  Colors.transparent,
                                            ),
                                            body: CarouselSlider(
                                              carouselController:
                                                  _controller,
                                              options: CarouselOptions(
                                                height:
                                                    MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                        .size
                                                        .height,
                                                enlargeCenterPage: true,
                                                autoPlay: false,
                                                aspectRatio: 16 / 9,

                                                onPageChanged:
                                                    (index, reason) {
                                                  setState(() {
                                                    _current = index;
                                                  });
                                                },

                                                autoPlayCurve:
                                                    Curves.easeIn,
                                                enableInfiniteScroll:
                                                    dList[index]
                                                                .postUrl!
                                                                .length ==
                                                            1
                                                        ? false
                                                        : true,
                                                viewportFraction: 1.0,
                                              ),
                                              items: name.map((item) {
                                                return Padding(
                                                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                                  child: Container(
                                                    height: MediaQuery.of(
                                                            context)
                                                        .size
                                                        .height,
                                                    width: MediaQuery.of(
                                                            context)
                                                        .size
                                                        .width,
                                                    margin: EdgeInsets
                                                        .symmetric(
                                                            vertical: 0),
                                                    child:
                                                        InteractiveViewer(
                                                      child: getRectangleImageForQRCode(
                                                          item.toString()),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                );
                                              }).toList(),
                                            ),
                                          );
                                        }));
                                      },
                                      child: getRectangleImageForQRCode(
                                          item.toString()),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                              }).toList(),
                            ),
                            dList[index].postUrl!.length == 1
                                ? Container()
                                : Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                                    child: AnimatedSmoothIndicator(
                                      activeIndex: _current,
                                      count:
                                          dList[index].postUrl!.length <= 2
                                              ? 2
                                              : 3,
                                      effect: JumpingDotEffect(
                                          dotHeight: 10.h,
                                          dotWidth: 10.h,
                                          jumpScale: .7,
                                          verticalOffset: 20,
                                          activeDotColor: Colors.red,
                                          dotColor: Colors.grey),
                                    ),
                                  )
```

What wrong in this code? Please help friends.